# Pass result from SQL Query to Odoo Qweb Report

Tags: report, odoo, qweb

I passed SQL query result to qweb report but the result is not rendered. I used the Postgres function to get the result,  I used function to use SQL function rank based on passed parameters. Views return all the results so the ranking based on some parameters didn't work.

````
self.env.cr.execute("""SELECT id,region,city,year,kpi,result,level,rank_no from kpi_rank('2', 2)""")
results = self.env.cr.fetchall()

if results is not None:
    return self.env.ref('kpi.action_kpi_rank_status_report').report_action(results)
else:
    raise UserError(_('No result found!')) ```
````

Answer (score 1):

Odoo experts `data` to be a dictionary and the first arguments to be `docids`, you can pass an empty list if you don't need to use self.

***Example:***

```
results = self.env.cr.fetchall()

if results is not None:
    data = {'results': results}
    return self.env.ref('kpi.action_kpi_rank_status_report').report_action([], data)
else:
    raise UserError(_('No result found!'))
```

*Note that you can check the number of rows that the last `execute()` produced using the cursor [rowcount](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.rowcount) attribute*

Comment: I solved the problem using the transient model. I stored the result I got from the Postgres function to a table created using transient model and retrieved it back using the ORM model search function.